Seeking alternative solution: $z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2 - 3 - 4i| = 2|z|. M = |z|_{\max}, m = |z|_{\min}$. Find $M^2 + m^2.$

$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2 - 3 - 4i| = 2|z|$. Let $M = |z|_{\max}, m = |z|_{\min}$. Find $M^2 + m^2.$

Solution:
$2|z| = |z^2 - 3 -4i| \geq ||z^2| - 5|$
$|z^2| = |z|^2 \implies 4|z|^2 \geq |z|^4 - 10|z|^2 + 25 \implies |z|^4 - 14|z|^2  + 25 \leq 0$
$\implies 0 < 7 - 2\sqrt{6} \leq |x|^2 \leq 7 + 2\sqrt{6} \implies M^2 + m^2 = 14$
I found this solution a bit too clever, and there also seems to be an assumption that equality will occur, while it's not necessarily so. We must verify that $z^2 = k(3 + 4i)$ for some positive $k.$ I wonder if somebody might have an alternative solution that may be more motivated or offers an alternative approach. Thank you!

I can't provide an alternative, but I can make that solution not so clever. (See below)

Rotate the complex plane around the origin and move $3+4i$ to $5$. This does not change $M,m$, and simplify the curve’s equation to $|z^2-5| = 2 |z|$.

Let’s imagine the 3D plot of $|z^2 - 5|$ and $2|z|$. The horizontal plane means $\mathbb{C}$, and the vertical axis means $|\cdot|$.
The plot of $2|z|$ is a cone, whose vertex is $(0,0,0)$.
The plot of $|z^2 - 5|$ is a bit complex. You can figure out that $|z^2 - 5| = \left|z-\sqrt{5}\right| \times \left|z + \sqrt{5}\right|$, a product of two distances; while as $|z| \to +\infty$, $|z^2 - 5| \approx |z|^2$, a paraboloid. So its plot is roughly a paraboloid, but its vertex is split into two points $a_{1,2} = \pm\sqrt{5}$.
The following plot is taken from Visual Complex Analysis §2.2.3 on Cassini oval.


Therefore, $|z^2 - 5| = 2|z|$, the intersection of the two plots, is two closed curves around $\pm\sqrt{5}$. We can guess that $\min$ and $\max$ are approached at somewhere $z \in \mathbb{R}$. To prove it, we should turn $|z^2 - 5| = 2|z|$ into an equation of $|z|$, and here comes that solution.


Contour plot of $|z^2-5| - 2|z|$:

Alternative derivation
First turn the $|\cdot|$ into conjugates.
$$
|z^2 - 5| = 2 |z|.
\iff (z^2-5) \left(\bar{z}^2 - 5\right) = 4 |z|^2.
\iff |z^2|^2 - 10 \operatorname{Re} z^2 + 25 = 4 |z^2|.
$$
Let $u := |z^2| \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\theta := \arg z^2 \in [0,2\pi)$, then the problem becomes $u^2 - 10 u \cos\theta + 25 = 4 u$, and $M^2 + m^2 = u_\text{max} + u_\text{min}$.

Hi, thanks so much for the detailed answer! Tbh, I'm a bit lost after your first step, but I appreciate the rotation idea, something I could imagine myself using for other problems. But I might have to come back to your answer later when I'm more mathematically mature :'(

Note that $$3+4i=(2+i)^2=(-2-i)^2$$
Let us label the points $$A(2+i), B(-2-i), O(0), P(z)$$ and $\varphi$ the angle at the vertex $P$ in the triangle $ABP.$
$O$ is a midpoint of $AB.$ In $\triangle ABP,$ Deuxième théorème de la médiane states
$$\overrightarrow{PA}\cdot \overrightarrow{PB}=|PO|^2-\frac{1}{4}|AB|^2,$$
which can be written as
$$|PA|\cdot |PB|\cos\varphi=|z|^2-5. \tag 1$$
On the other hand, the equation
$$|z^2 - 3 - 4i| = 2|z|$$
rewrites
$$|PA|\cdot |PB|=2|z|. \tag 2$$
$(1), (2)$ lead to a quadratic equation
$$|z|^2-2|z|\cos\varphi -5=0$$ with the only positive solution
$$|z|=\cos\varphi + \sqrt{\cos^2\varphi +5}.$$
The largest cosine gives $M= |z|_{max},$ the smallest cosine gives $m=|z|_{min}.$ This occurs in degenerate triangles $ABP,$ where $A,B,P$ are aligned and satisfy $(2).$ Specifically:

If $P$ lies on the segment $AB,$ then $\cos\varphi =1;$
If $P$ lies outside $AB,$ then $\cos\varphi =-1.$
On the figure, the set of points satisfying $|z^2 - 3 - 4i| = 2|z|$ is blue.

To finish, $$M=1+\sqrt6,\quad m=-1+\sqrt6,$$
therefore $$M^2+m^2=14.$$


We have that for $z\neq 0$
$$|z^2 - 3 - 4i| = 2|z| \iff z^2=2ze^{i\theta}+3+4i \iff z^2-2ze^{i\theta}-3-4i=0$$
then
$$z=e^{i\theta} \pm \sqrt{e^{i2\theta}+3+4i}$$
and the extreme values for the modulus are obtained when $e^{i2\theta}= \frac{3+4i}{5}=e^{i\phi}$ that is
$$z=e^{i\left(\frac {\phi}2+k\pi\right)} \pm \sqrt{6e^{i\phi}}=e^{i\left(\frac {\phi}2+k\pi\right)} \pm \sqrt{6}e^{i\left(\frac {\phi}2+r\pi\right)}=e^{i\frac {\phi}2}\left(e^{ik\pi}\pm \sqrt 6e^{ir\pi}\right)$$
with $k, r =0,1$ therefore
$$\sqrt 6 -1\le |z|\le \sqrt 6 +1$$
